# Warning: trim() Invalid '..'-range, '..'-range needs to be incrementing

Tags: php, trim

I'm using trim() to get rid of characters from a string, but I get the warning message in the question title. How can I get rid of the warning, I've tried arranging the values in several different ways.

**Code:**

```
trim($temp2_description[0], "\xA0..\x0d..\x0a..\x09");
```

**Also tried:**

```
trim($temp2_description[0], "\x09..\x0a..\x0d..\xA0");
```

**Hex values of the part of the string I want to trim:**

```
a0
a0
a0
a0
a0
0d
0a
09
09
09
09
09
09
09
a0
0d
0a
09
09
09
09
09
```

How can I specify the trim function so it doesn't return the warning message in my question title?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your ranges are incorrect. They have to be `start..endstart..endstart..end`. You've got `start..end..end..end`.

Comment: Can you give an example, I'm not understanding what endstart would be?

Comment: `trim($var, "\x0a..\x0d"` is effectively the same thing as `trim($var, "\x0a\x0b\x0c\x0d")`. You're saying "from x09 to x0a to x0d to xa0", which would be translated to "any chars between x09 to xA0 inclusive". You have to specify a start and end for each `..` range you specify.